# Not able to send Wix SourceDir path with spaces to custom action ExeCommand

Tags: wix, wix3.5

i am not to able to pass "[SourceDir]" path when SourceDir path has spaces.

ex: SourceDir = "C:\Temp\Setup" i am able to send "C:\Temp\Setup" path to custom action
SourceDir = "C:\Temp setup\Setup" wix passing only "C:\Temp" to custom action

```
 ExeCommand="[SourceDir]Setup"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose it in quotes like so:

```
ExeCommand="&quot;[SourceDir]Setup&quot;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I also had to put in a second set of "s but with an escaping \

```
&quot;\&quot;[Path with spaces]\&quot;&quot;
```

I believe this is because the text gets interpreted when it gets compiled by wix and then again when it gets installed. Or something like that.

Thanks

David

Comment: watch out if your [path with spaces] has a trailing \. I've had to add a space after it, so that it doesn't cancel out the \ in \&quot;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "\" after [SourceDir] before the last quote:

ExeCommand="&quot;[SourceDir]\&quot;"

As last quote inside [SourceDir] escapes the last quote (&quot;) by default.

Applies to wixl.